# Объединение вложенных объектов по ключу. JS

Tags: javascript

Есть объект

```
Объект 1
{
 1: {
        id:1, // id: совпадает с ключом данного объекта, уникальное значение для всех объектов
        name: 'test1', // name: слово на латинице и всегда уникально,
        value: 1, // значение которое и нужно синхронизировать
        ...//другие поля
   },
 2: {
        id:2, // id в данном объекте совпадает с ключом данного объекта
        name: 'test2',
        value: 1,
        ...//другие поля
   }
3: {
        id:3, // id в данном объекте совпадает с ключом данного объекта
        name: 'test3',
        value: 1,
        ...//другие поля
   }
 ...// объект может содержать до 200 вложенных объектов
}
```

далее по ходу выполнения программы появляется ещё такие объекты структурно похожие на данный, которые могут содержать поля `name`, которые уже встречались в предыдущем объекте.
Например:

```
Объект 2
{
     50: {
            id:50, 
            name: 'what', 
            value: 2,
            ...//другие поля
       },
     51: {
            id:51, 
            name: 'test1', // данное имя встречалось в "объекте 1"
            value: 2,
            ...//другие поля
       }
     ...//объект может содержать до 200 вложенных объектов
 }

Объект 3
 {
      67: {
              id:67, 
              name: 'test2', 
              value: 3,
              ...//другие поля
           },
      68: {
              id:68, 
              name: 'test4',
              value: 3,
              ...//другие поля
           }
         ...//объект может содержать до 200 вложенных объектов
 }
```

Результат:

```
{
     51: {
            id:51, 
            name: 'test1', // данное значение было в "Объекте 1" и "Объекте 2" т.к. "Объекте 2" был взят в цикле позже чем "Объекте 1", то в результирующий взят объект из "Объект 2"
            value: 2, 
            ...//другие поля
        },
    67: {
            id:67, 
            name: 'test2', // из объекта 3
            value: 3,
            ...//другие поля
       },
    3: {
            id:3, 
            name: 'test3', // из объекта 1
            value: 1,
            ...//другие поля
       },
   50: {
            id:50, 
            name: 'what',  // из объекта 2
            value: 2,
            ...//другие поля
       },
   68: {
            id:68, 
            name: 'test4', // из объекта 3
            value: 3,
            ...//другие поля
       }
     ... // объект может содержать до 200 вложенных объектов
    }
```

Т.е. в `результирующий объект` нужно поместить только уникальные объекты по полю `name`. последние значение берётся из объекта который в цикле встретился `последним`. Порядок сортировки объекта не важен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идея простая: вначале подобавлять объекты в словарь, где ключем будет поле `name`, а потом словарь сконвертировать в результирующий объект

```js
const obj1 = {
  1: {
    id: 1, // id: совпадает с ключом данного объекта, уникальное значение для всех объектов
    name: 'test1', // name: слово на латинице и всегда уникально,
    value: 1, // значение которое и нужно синхронизировать
  },
  2: {
    id: 2, // id в данном объекте совпадает с ключом данного объекта
    name: 'test2',
    value: 1
  },
  3: {
    id: 3, // id в данном объекте совпадает с ключом данного объекта
    name: 'test3',
    value: 1
  }
};

const obj2 = {
  50: {
    id: 50,
    name: 'what',
    value: 2
  },
  51: {
    id: 51,
    name: 'test1', // данное имя встречалось в "объекте 1"
    value: 2
  }
};

const obj3 = {
  67: {
    id: 67,
    name: 'test2',
    value: 3
  },
  68: {
    id: 68,
    name: 'test4',
    value: 3
  }
};

const accum = {};

function addObj(accum, obj) {
  for (let i in obj) {
    accum[obj[i].name] = {
      obj: obj[i],
      idx: i
    }
  }
}

function convertAccum(accum) {
  const res = {};
  for (let i in accum) {
    const obj = accum[i];
    res[obj.idx] = obj.obj;
  }
  return res;
}

addObj(accum, obj1);
addObj(accum, obj2);
addObj(accum, obj3);
const res = convertAccum(accum);
console.log(res);
```

P.S. Этот код будет работать если индексы в исходных объектах уникальны

Comment: Спасибо! очень помогли.

Comment: @AlexKnow Если мой ответ решил вашу проблему, то отметьте его как верный

Answer (score 1):

Вы слышали об [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)?

```js
// Входящие данные
let objA = { [1]: {name: '1' }, [2]: {name: '2'}, [3]: {name: '3'}, [4]: {name: '4'}};
let objB = { [5]: {name: '4' }, [6]: {name: '5'}, [7]: {name: '6'}, [8]: {name: '7'}};
let objC = { [9]: {name: 'a' }, [10]: {name: 'b'}, [11]: {name: 'c'}, [12]: {name: 'd'}};

// Зададим несколько констанций
const { entries: E, fromEntries: F, assign: A } = Object,
  [R,I,P] = [ a => [{},...a],
              ([name,data]) => [data.id,data],
              ([id,data]) => [data.name,A(data,{id})] ],
  N = o => F(E(o).map(P));

// Это всё, что вам нужно
let objR = F(E(A(...R([objA,objB,objC].map(N)))).map(I));


// На выходе получаем objR

// JSON.stringify и прочие .replace() здесь для форматирования вывода
// то есть, этот код в условие задачи не входит
console.log('obj = ',JSON.stringify(objR).replace(/(^{|},)/g,'$1\n').replace(/^"(\w+)":/mg,'[$1]:'));
```

Comment: А как Object.assign учитывает что надо проверять уникальность поля name ?

Comment: Так по какому полю нужна уникальность по ключу или по name? Сейчас быстро исправим!

Comment: Как я понял из описания, по полю name.

Comment: А что делать, когда name одинаковый, а ключи разные?

Comment: Должен остаться тот который придет последним.

Comment: @Lukas так сейчас так и есть)) или я запутался, в любом случае решение будет если не в одно так в три вызова функции

Comment: @DiD по полю name

Comment: @DiD ключи всегда уникальные это секвенция, но в результирующий объект нужно помещать по полю name, который пришёл последним

Comment: @AlexKnow исправил ответ, решение конечно получилось так себе... Я еще подумаю как решить по-нагляднее. Но как бы, без циклов, на манер монад и прочей функциональщины.

Comment: @DiD Спасибо! очень помогли.